# How can I change selection list with an editor

Tags: javascript

I have 2 selection lists

```
<select Multiple name="SelectOut" id="SelectOut" size="15">
<select Multiple name="SelectIn" id="SelectIn" size="15">
```

In between I have two buttons `<--` & `-->`. Using this button I can move the list left to right or right to left.

User inconvenience is that **copy and paste** is not working with selection lists. He wants to replace the right selection list `SelectIn` with a text editor. He paste the content to that editor (Usually a big columns o). After pasting it should exactly behave like the selection list. He should be able to move the list item to left, add more items from left, should be sort it etc....

How can I achieve this?

In the right side instead of a selection list, I need a text editor. Or I should be able enable the copy and paste enable in the right section list:). For the user major inconvience is he has to select one ore more list items from the left selection list to right. Insted he should be able to cut and past the list from an excel sheet column to the editor. One more work around , I can see is , paste the content to an extra text editor and pressing a button that editor content should appear as a list item in right selection list exactly same as in the Excel sheet column. 
TIA
-Philip-

Comment: You want to do something like this http://www.montparnas.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2006/11/form-select-list-boxes.jpg where the right column is a text box, aren't you? If the answer is yes, try to use http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Answer (score 4):

do you want something like this

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/s6oknL75/1/)

**JS**

```
function shiftRight()
{
    var selItem = document.forms[0].list1.selectedIndex;
    if (selItem == -1)
    {
        window.alert("Select Item From List")
    }
    else
    {
        document.forms[0].list2.add(document.forms[0].list1[selItem], null);
    }
}

function shiftLeft()
{
    var selItem = document.forms[0].list2.selectedIndex;
    if (selItem == -1)
    {
        window.alert("Select Item From List")
    }
    else
    {
        document.forms[0].list1.add(document.forms[0].list2[selItem], null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose that he wants something similar to what you posted but with an additional feature: to paste the options to the right side.